# Has there been a new version of the C++ standard published?

Tags: c++

> The following article contains a link to all current and draft versions of the standard.
>   See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/14065

I was just checked the [ISO site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/) to see what the latest version of the draft standard was.

I came up with two versions I had not seen previously:
[N3690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)
[N3691](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf)

There are a couple of oddities here.

1. N3691 is published on 2013-05-16 this is after N3690 2013-05-15 ***BUT*** NS3690 seems to be the later version (N3691 is the previous version of N3690).
2. When you open up N3690 it has non of the wording indicating it is a draft.

Does this mean we are now using C++13?

Comment: Sorry to say it's still at least a year before the supposed C++14. Hey, 3/6 years beats 8/13 years, though.

Comment: sorry, but I have to downvote this: both links you provided contain the word draft on the title page. N3690 has a big fat warning box, and N3691 even has the word Draft in its title.

Comment: @TemplateRex: N3691:=>"Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++" N3690:=>"Programming Languages — C++"

Comment: Indeed, and you didn't have to go through a paywall to get to it.

Comment: @LokiAstari But there are two big fat boxes on pages i and ii, with the word draft in it. Maybe they could use a bold type face, I dunno, but the first one has a Warning sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're currently in the balloting process for the next standard.  What you found are drafts for C++14.

From the warning on the first page of N3690:

> This document is not an ISO International Standard. It is distributed for review and comment. It is subject
>   to change without notice and **may not** be referred to as an International Standard.
>   Recipients of this **draft** are invited to submit, with their comments, notiﬁcation of any relevant patent rights
>   of which they are aware and to provide supporting documentation.

My guess is that N3690 is the version they're voting on, so it has to look as close as possible to the real thing.  Version N3691 would be the latest working copy and not subject to vote.

Comment: Then I would have expected the words "Draft Standard". But hey I did not even know they were voting. Do you have a link.

Comment: I think one of the recent posts on the Standard C++ blog indicated they were starting the voting process.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: What about the oddities in publish date and revision order. Is that just a typo?

Comment: First line of this post has it: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/07/summer-standards-papers-mailing-available

Comment: The two documents are only one day apart.  If the ballot copy and working draft are handled by different people, it's plausible that they could have been numbered out of order.  Perhaps they need a better consensus algorithm? :-P

Comment: I know now they have a blog. That's one new think I learned today.

Answer (score 1):

The current C++ standard was adopted in 2011. The papers you're looking at are **drafts** for the future.